# Store scraped data from news website using PostgreSQL through flask_sqlalchemy

Tags: python, postgresql, flask, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

**The idea of ​​the project in a nutshell:**
I want to store the data that I scraped from news sites in a Postgres database and then query this data and display it in a site using the Flask framework.

**Type of data I want to scrape**: Title, Link, Image, date (save date as string, because the format of date for each website will be different), Type of news article (Political, economic and sports news).

I create one-to-many relationships in a database (one type has many news data).

**I used BeautifulSoup and requests libraries for scraping**

---

**models.py**

```
import os
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

db = SQLAlchemy()

class Type(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'Type'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    type_name = db.Column(db.String(80))
    news = db.relationship('News', backref='type_news', lazy='dynamic')
    
    def __init__(self, type_name):
        self.type_name = type_name
    
    def __repr__(self):
        return f'<Type {self.id}>'


class News(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'news'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    title = db.Column(db.String(200))
    link = db.Column(db.String(200))
    date = db.Column(db.String(200))
    img = db.Column(db.String(300))

    type_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('type.type_id'))
    type = db.relationship('Type')
    
    def __init__(self, title, link, date, img):
        self.title = title
        self.link = link
        self.date = date
        self.img = img
        
    def __repr__(self):
        return f'<News {self.id}>'
```

**config.py**

```
from os import environ, path



db_host = environ.get('DB_HOST', default='localhost')
db_name = environ.get('DB_NAME', default='NewsSqlDB')
db_password = environ.get('DB_PASSWORD', default='securepass')
db_port = environ.get('DB_PORT', default='5432')
db_user = environ.get('DB_USERNAME', default='postgres')


# Database
SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = f"postgresql://{db_user}:{db_password}@{db_host}:{db_port}/{db_name}"
SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS = False
```

****init**.py**

```
import os
from flask import Flask


def create_app(config_filename=None):
    app = Flask(__name__, instance_relative_config=False)
    app.config.from_mapping(
        SECRET_KEY=os.getenv('SECRET_KEY') or b'\x01\xeb\xab/\x026\xd3\xc4?\xfd\x02\x1b\x058\x81`\xe6['
                                              b'\xd6\x8bR\n\xec5',

    )
    if config_filename is None:
        app.config.from_pyfile('config.py', silent=True)
    else:
        app.config.from_mapping(config_filename)

    from .models import db
    db.init_app(app)

    return app
```

**How data looks like after scraping**: This is how I save my data after scraping website (I Save a lot of data for each type).

```
data = {
    'Type': 'Sport',
    'Title': ['any title about sport', 'any title about sport', 'any title about sport', ...],
    'Link': ['https://www.ninanews.com/Website/News/Details?key=923825', ...],
    'Date': ['الجمعة 27 , آب 2021 19:08', ...],
    'Image': 
      ['https://images.weserv.nl/url=ninanews.net/Uploads/Images/2021/8/923825c67
3d87e-ef7c-4d68-ad58-1981d5681284.jpg&w=200&h=150&t=absolute', ...],
}
```

**scrape.py**

```
data = {}
for i in [2, 4, 5]:
    url = f'https://www.ninanews.com/Website/News/List?key={i}'
    data["Type"] = get_url_type(url)[0]
    data["Title"] = get_title(i, pages)
    data["Link"] = get_link(i, pages)
    data["Date"] = get_date(i, pages)
    data["Image"] = get_images(i, pages)
    news = News(title=data['Title'], link=data['Link'], date=data['Date'], img=data['Image'])
    type_ = Type(type_name=data['Type'])
    type_.news.append(news)
    db.session.add(type_)
    db.session.add(news)
    db.session.commit()
```

**app.py**

```
from News import create_app
from News.models import db, News, Type

app = create_app()


@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    type_ = Type.query.order_by(Type.type_name).all()
    titles = News.query.order_by(News.title).all()
    return f"Titles: {type_}" # Titles: []


if __name__ == '__main__':
    with app.app_context():
        import News.scrape_ninanews
        db.create_all()
        app.run()
```

**My problem**: I can't save those data to postgresql database(flask_sqlalchemy) so I can display it in my site.
I see this this error:

```
[SQL: INSERT INTO news (title, link, date, img, type_id) VALUES (%(titl
e)s, %(link)s, %(date)s, %(img)s, %(type_id)s) RETURNING news.id]
[parameters: {'title': ['العراق يحرز المركز الثاني في بطولة العالم بالق
وة البدنية', 'باير ليفركوزن يتصدر الدوري الألماني', 'منتخبنا الوطني يغا
در إلى كوريا الجنوبية', 'اتحاد  ... (336 characters truncated) ... كأس
السوبر', 'الجوية يخطف الدولي علاء عباس', 'غدا.. طائرة خاصة تنقل منتخبنا
 إلى كوريا الجنوبية', 'منتخبنا الأولمبي يخسر أمام منتخب ليبيا الأول ودي
اً'], 'link': ['https://www.ninanews.com/Website/News/Details?key=92420
2', 'https://www.ninanews.com/Website/News/Details?key=924200', 'https:
//www.ninanews.com/Web ... (480 characters truncated) ... site/News/Det
ails?key=923773', 'https://www.ninanews.com/Website/News/Details?key=92
3757', 'https://www.ninanews.com/Website/News/Details?key=923755'], 'da
te': ['السبت 28 , آب 2021 21:14', 'السبت 28 , آب 2021 20:53', 'السبت 28
 , آب 2021 20:12', 'السبت 28 , آب 2021 19:34', 'السبت 28 , آب 2021 17:1
3', 'الجمعة 2 ... (72 characters truncated) ... :13', 'الجمعة 27 , آب 2
021 14:29', 'الجمعة 27 , آب 2021 14:19', 'الجمعة 27 , آب 2021 14:12', '
الجمعة 27 , آب 2021 13:37', 'الجمعة 27 , آب 2021 13:34'], 'img': ['http
s://images.weserv.nl/?url=ninanews.net/Uploads/Images/2021/8/924202-e4e
b72b7-f1d5-46f3-ae45-543e35073a79.jpg&w=200&h=150&t=absolute', 'https:/
/i ... (1229 characters truncated) ... =absolute', 'https://images.wese
rv.nl/?url=ninanews.net/Uploads/Images/2021/8/923755-48f28451-08c1-452b
-9de5-14bb07e842fa.jpg&w=200&h=150&t=absolute'], 'type_id': 1}]
(Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/14/9h9h)
```

Comment: With problems like this, it helps to break them in to pieces, which makes writing tests much simpler. "How to scrape the data into a string", and "How to store a string into PostreSQL" are clearly separable. The meeting point is a string--details from one don't affect details from the other.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

The length of the columns in the `News` table is 200. The data of some of the fields you try to insert is > 200. You can set the length to higher value and try again.

Comment: Unfortunately, that doesn't work, I tried to set it to 600 and more but that not working.